# Overlapping regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to come up with a regular expression that can capture overlapping patterns in python, but with no success. I need to be able to detect the following information from a string:

```
  'OC on pin 32 or 31'
  'OC on pin 32 or pin 31'
  'OC on pin 32 31'
  'OC on pin 32'
```

On all examples above, the regular expression should yield the results: (32,31) and (32) for the last line.

I've just started learning python and how to use regular expressions, and what I came up with was the followig:

```
'^.*OC.*pin\s*([0-9][0-9])(?:\s*or\s*)?(?:\s*pin\s*)?([0-9][0-9])?'
```

It only works for the first line in the examples above, from what I read, it seems to be overlapping when the second 'pin' is in the input string.

```
pattern = '^.*OC.*pin\s*([0-9][0-9])(?:\s*or\s*)?(?:\s*pin\s*)?([0-9][0-9])?'
str = 'OC on pin 32'
re.findall(pattern, str)
[('32', '')]
```

for the other case:

```
str = 'OC on pin 32 or pin 31'
re.findall(pattern, str)
[('31', '')]
```

Is there a way to catch all of the cases above without having to alter the string brefore using the regex?

Comment: Can you be more precisre about what you want to match? It is not clear what you mean by overlapping in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem comes from the fact that `.*` matches greedily.

```
pattern = '^.*OC.*pin\s*([0-9][0-9])(?:\s*or\s*)?(?:\s*pin\s*)?([0-9][0-9])?'
#                ^ will consume way more than you want
```

A solution is to use `.*?` to match non-greedily. I could come up with that solution that works.

```
pattern = r'OC.*?pin\s*(\d+)\s*(?:or)?\s*(?:pin)?\s*(\d+)?'
#               ^ this indicates that .*? should not attempt to consume 'pin'

string = """
    OC on pin 32 or 31'
    OC on pin 32 or pin 31'
    OC on pin 32 31'
    OC on pin 32'
"""

match = re.findall(pattern, string)
# match: [('32', '31'), ('32', '31'), ('32', '31'), ('32', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already answered here (with no explanation), you are over-specifying your search pattern.

If you want to extract groups of digits, the pattern `\d+` does that just fine.

While you can do syntax validation that the string begins with `OC on pin` you can jam that into the regex, but it is more readable and more efficient to use a predicate like

```
if str.startswith('OC on pin'):
    ...
```

Comment: From the regexp they provided, I think OP wants the 'on' to be optional.